# Sizing with wx.aui.AuiManager's AddPane

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

In an application using wxPython, I use the wx.aui.AuiManager for the layout of the main frame. For a certain event triggered by the user, two panes should appear in the frame. I can add them so that they appear in the right spot (to the right) in the frame, but I have been struggling with the size of each pane. If `self._mgr = wx.aui.AuiManager()`, I simply use

```
self._mgr.AddPane(mypanel1, wx.aui.AuiPaneInfo().
                      Name("MyPanel1").
                      Caption("MyPanel1").
                      MinSize(MyPanel1.GetBestSize()).
                      BestSize(MyPanel1.GetBestSize()).
                      Right().Layer(1).Position(0).CloseButton(True).
                      MaximizeButton(False))

self._mgr.AddPane(mypanel2, wx.aui.AuiPaneInfo().
                      Name("MyPanel2").
                      Caption("MyPanel2").
                      MinSize(MyPanel2.GetBestSize()).
                      BestSize(MyPanel2.GetBestSize()).
                      Right().Layer(1).Position(1).CloseButton(True).
                      MaximizeButton(False))

self._mgr.Update()
```

The problem is that when running the software and opening these two panels (they pop up at the same time), the height of each panel is height_frame * 0.5, but I want their height to be say height_panel1 = 0.3 * height_frame, and height_panel2 = 0.7 * height_frame.

See example below. The top image is what I end up with, panel1 and panel 2 have the same height (half of the available height in the frame). The bottommost is what I want, where each panel have some ratio between themself.

```
    +---------------------------------+    
    |                    +-----------+|    ^ F
    |    MAIN FRAME      | panel1    ||    | r
    |                    |           ||    | a
    |                    |           ||    | m
    |                    |           ||    | e
    |                    +-----------+|    |    
    |                    | panel2    ||    | h
    |                    |           ||    | e
    |                    |           ||    | i
    |                    |           ||    | g
    |                    +-----------+|    v h
    +---------------------------------+      t


    +---------------------------------+
    |                    +-----------+|
    |    MAIN FRAME      | panel1    ||
    |                    |           ||
    |                    +-----------+|
    |                    | panel2    ||
    |                    |           ||
    |                    |           ||
    |                    |           ||
    |                    |           ||
    |                    |           ||
    |                    +-----------+|
    +---------------------------------+
```

Attempts that I have done to solve this is to play with the MinSize and BestSize parameters in the AddPane-call (i.e. `BestSize(wx.Size(1000, 1000))`), but the result is that the width of the two panels change, but the height of each panel is still the same (half the height of the parent frame)!

Note that I would like this ratio between panel1 and panel2 (30/70) to be the same, even if rescaling the parent main frame, but the user should also be able to rescale them by dragging the panels "as usual" (this is what I have to do right now to get from the 50/50 to 30/70...but this feature should of course still be available).

Are there any suggestions/solutions on how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by dynamically calculating panels minimal and best sizes.

Comment: Thank you for your skybobbi! After a lot of fiddling around, I found that adding the following lines right before the `self.Update()` will fix it: `self._mgr.GetPane("MyPanel1").dock_proportion = 10` and `self._mgr.GetPane("MyPanel1").dock_proportion = 25`.